# Adding an array inside Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add an array of questions to my schema. But it doesn't work. I got an empty array. Do I have to use several schemes?

```
    var questionnaireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    seniority: String,
    questions: [{
        secondQuestion: String,
        thirdQuestion: Array,
        fourthQuestion: String,
        fifthQuestion: String,  
        sixthQuestion:String,
        seventhQuestion: String,
        eighthQuestion: String, 
        ninthQuestion:String,
        tenthQuestion: String,
    eleventhQuestion: String
}]
});
```

My callback
    questions: []

My data:

```
$scope.data = {
           'seniority': $scope.answers.firstQuestion,
           'secondQuestion': $scope.answers.secondQuestion,
           'thirdQuestion': {
                    'Account': $scope.answers.thirdQuestionAccount,
                    'debitCard': $scope.answers.thirdQuestionDebitCard,

                                            },
           },
           'fourthQuestion': $scope.answers.fourthQuestion,

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html). You have to specify the array as object.

```
var questionnaireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    seniority: String,
    questions: {
        secondQuestion: String,
        thirdQuestion: Array,
        fourthQuestion: String,
        fifthQuestion: String,  
        sixthQuestion:String,
        seventhQuestion: String,
        eighthQuestion: String, 
        ninthQuestion:String,
        tenthQuestion: String,
        eleventhQuestion: String
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you were helpful